# Search Query Variables in SharePoint 2010 (Federated Search)

Tags: search, federated-search, search-query, opensearch

I am working on an OpenSearch end-point that will be used solely by SharePoint environments (both 2010 and 2013) in federated search results.  When configuring results sources in **SharePoint 2013**, there are a lot of variables I can use, such as {Site.ID} and {User.Name}.  There is a list of these variables on [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj683123(v=office.15)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj683123%28v=office.15%29).

I need to know is what variables are available in **SharePoint 2010**.  At minimum, I need to know the user who is making the request and the site they are making the request from.  (When searching from specific sites, the OpenSearch end-point needs to only return results pertaining to that site, whereas all other sites should get all search results, etc.).

Is this information published somewhere? I can't seem to find anything about what variables SharePoint 2010 makes available.

Comment: did you ever get an answer for your question? I am facing exactly the same issue. How did you resolve this? Thanks!